# Calcular data de vencimento

Tags: php, mysql

Eu possuo uma coluna chamada START em formato DATETIME no MySQL e eu gostaria de checar se cada row está vencido e/ou quantos dias faltam para vencer aquele row, levando em consideração que o row vence em 30 dias depois da data de START.

Pensei em pegar a data e e subtrair com a data atual mas não sei se tem como em PHP, como faze-lo?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    START, 
    DATE_ADD(START, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS DATA_VENCIMENTO,      
    DATADIFF(START, DATE_ADD(START, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AS DIFERENCA
FROM 
    TABELA
```

Nesse `SELECT` você consegue recuperar a diferença de dias entre uma **Data Start** e a **Data de Vencimento** (30 dias depois).

E no PHP você pode verificar se o número é negativo, se for é porquê já venceu:

```
if($res['DIFERENCA'] < 0)
    echo "Vencido!";
else
    echo "Em dia";
```

Comment: Arrumei essa linha: `DATEDIFF(START, NOW())` AS DIFERENCA e funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 2):

SELECT start FROM table WHERE DATE_SUB(start, INTERVAL 30 DAY) < now();

Usando o valor de "start", ele adiciona 30 dias reais e pega os registros que forem MAIOR que a data do momento da execução do script.

EX: data de expiração = 2015-09-09 (data start projeta + 30 dias) e hoje é 2015-09-08, esta linha não seria retornada.

Espero ter sido claro.